# Qmail mail queue behaviour

Tags: linux, email-server, email

hello I am on ubuntu linux distribution

I am using qmail. I have some mails blocked in queue. how can I check why those are not forwarding correctly ?

```
root@server:~# /var/qmail/bin/qmail-qread
18 Sep 2013 11:55:30 GMT  #1550131  54986  <myaccount@gmail.com> 
        remote  ereallstaff@tiscali.it
```

Are the message shown by the command

Thanks

Comment: You can check qmaillogs to see why the emails are in queue?

Answer (score 0):

check your maillog /var/log/maillog when qmial try send that message.

maybe target server tiscali.it tell somethink like:
 - server isn't available
 - you are temporary in spam list